# Easy differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve:$$y'=\sqrt{y-y^2}$$

My result is $y=\cos^2(\frac{x}{2}+c)$ where c is a constant...the solution given in my book is:$$y=\sin^2(\frac{x}{2}+c)$$...I really can't figure out, help please :D

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\sin(\theta + \pi / 2) = \cos (\theta)
$$
So that the solution in the book is
$$
\sin^2( x/2 + c' + \pi/2) = \cos^2(x/2 + c')
$$
where $c' = c - \pi/2$. So actually both answers are the same (because $c$ is simply a constant).

Comment: when you derive $y$ you get $−\cos(x/2+c)\sin(x/2+c)$ but if you substitute $y$ in the differential equation the equality isn't satisfied...instead if I use $y=\sin^2(x/2+c)$ the equation is satisfied

Comment: @user155594 what do you mean when you derive $y$? Where are you getting $-\cos(x/2+c')\sin(x/2+c')$?

Comment: I mean find the derivative

Comment: @user155594 yes and what do you get if you plug $y=\cos^2(x/2+c)$ into the RHS? You get 
$$
\sqrt{\cos^2(x/2+c) - \cos^4(x/2+c)} = \cos(x/2+c)\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x/2+c)} = \cos(x/2+c)\sin(x/2+c)
$$
Thus the sides are off by a negative, is this where you're finding issue?

Comment: Yes...I just remember that $\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}=\left | \sin(x) \right |$

Comment: maybe it could be correct whereas $\left | \sin(x) \right |=- \sin(x)$ or $\sin(x)$

Comment: @user155594 exactly, that's what I was going to say, you need to remember that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.

Comment: @user155594 nonetheless it's curious since $-\cos(x/2+c)\sin(x/2+c) \neq \cos(x/2+c)|\sin(x/2+c)|$ for every $x$. Let me ponder a more precise reasoning.

Comment: @user155594 technically putting $y$ to be $\sin^2(x/2+c)$ you run into the same issue, instead on the right side you'll get $\sin(x/2+c)|\cos(x/2+c)|$. Also note technically to pull out $\sin(x/2+c)$ from the square root you're actually doing the a similar thing. That is technically the right side is $|\sin(x/2+c)\cos(x/2+c)|$ for both cases.

Comment: @user155594 you should mark this question as your answer if it answered your question.